# $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=f(1)$; show $f(a)=f(a+\frac12)$ for some $a\in[0,\frac12]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

> Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on the interval $[0, 1]$ with $f(0) = f(1)$. Show that $f(a)=f(a+\frac12)$ for some $a\in[0,\frac12]$.
>
> *Hint*: Let $g(x)=f(x+\frac12)-f(x)$ and use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Hint 1:  Let g(x)=f(x+1/2)-f(x) and use the Intermediate-value theorem.  Hint 2: Use the hint given.  Hint 3: if you don't understand the hint given tell us why it was giving you problem.  So far as I can tell all information is there.

Comment: Okay,  a legitimate hint.  At x = 0,g(0) =  f(x + 1/2) -f(x) = f(1/2) - f(0).  And x = 1/2, the g(1/2) = f(x+1/2) - f(x) = f(1) - f(1/2) = f(0) - f(1/2)=-g(0).  If f is continuous so is g.  So... it's all there....

Answer (score 3):

you have
$g(0)=f(\frac{1}{2})-f(0)$
and
$g(\frac{1}{2})=f(1)-f(\frac{1}{2})$
which is the opposite of $g(0)$

since $f(0)=f(1)$.

thus

$g(0)g(\frac{1}{2})\leq0$

and since $g$ is continuous on

$[0,\frac{1}{2}]$

you conclude.